# Python TurtleGraphics - Making a randomly moving turtle?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a randomly moving turtle here by following these steps in a function I've called drunk_turtle():

Repeat the following as many times as you like:

- Randomly choose an integer, called rand_num, from -1 to 1 (i.e. randomly set rand_num to be -1, 0, or 1)
- Make the turtle turn right rand_num * 90 degrees;
- Go forward 5, 10, or 15 --- choose this value at random. 5 = 1*5, 10 = 2*5, 15 = 3*5, ...

How do I make code that does this? I don't really get how to get my random integer or get it to pick randomly 5, 10, or 15. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all of that information in [the Python random manual](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html).

> `random.randint(a, b)`
>
> ```
> Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.
> ```

So you would do `random.randint(-1,1)` to get a number from -1, 0, or 1.

To get 5, 10, or 15, just do `5 * random.randint(1,3)`.

If you had a more complicated set of numbers to choose from -- say (6, 25, or 33) -- you can do  `random.choice([6, 25, 33])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
**You can use the following code to move your turtle randomly**

from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random


t = Turtle()
colors = ["lime green", "dark orange", "green yellow"   , "gold", "dark violet", "red"]

direction =[0, 90, 180, 270]

for _ in range(50):
    t.pensize(7)
    t.forward(20)
    t.color(random.choice(colors))
    t.setheading(random.choice(direction))
```

Comment: Even you can have a random list for distance , it will be more beautiful .